# How best to appraise a bicycle .... attn collectors!

Tags: shopping

Other than having been a serious rider, having owned/fixed-up/sold/bought about 30 or 40 bikes in the past few years...I'd be useless buying or selling even 1 bike.

how would the average consumer know if they have "a valuable bike" due to quality/brand/options... and-or bikes that are out-of-production and go up due to supply & demand?

Car consumers have the kelley blue book.

bikes don't tell you mileage -not nearly as definitively as an odometer in a vehicle. As example, the most valueble bike I ever owned/sold was an E-Moto, the company is defunct. This lightweight mtn bike had a 12v battery, power front & rear disc brakes, it even delivered electricity to the derailleur. The bike was to be marketed to Japanese commuters. It folds up like a brief-case! the company being defunct, the high-tech features and usefulness make it a fav. amoung collectors.

I first got acquainted w/ a townie because my associate was using one for his daily-rider. it was an electra, with 24-speeds (no longer made, design or gearset)...to the untrained eye it is an avg. hybrid, but I know it's worth well >$1000 and the E-Moto, though we sold for $3000-- couldve fetched higher. It was also 2012 - that bike could be worth $8 to $10k.

**how do the people that don't eat, sleep and breathe bikes [the way we do] know when they are getting a good deal ... *or the shaft?***

Comment: The title is attn collectors then the question is average consumer.  Did you try Google "bicycle blue book"?  Specialty / rare items are not liquid.   The average consumer is not into specialty / rare items so they are not going to buy your E-Moto you sold  for $3000 in the first place.

Comment: @Frisbee While I am voting to close, I think he's hoping to get hints from collectors. But all the collectors I know are into some niche area, and what they have learned is not available for free.

Comment: yes @Frisbee I was seeking hints from collectors on how to help non-expert-bicyclists purchase a cool bike at a good price. Plenty of casual riders want a sweet, head-turning bike; but they are vulnerable to hucksters. In this category (as most) information should be free but I understand how/why in this case, it may not be.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it's not too rare you could do an Ebay watch to see what similar bikes sell for on Ebay.  I would expect more variation in price in more esoteric stuff, since you tend to have a smaller pool of items and buyers.

Comment: an acceptable answer, though it is more of an idea...online comparison shopping meets the criteria. I get asked to help friends go look at bikes all the time before they buy them, or to help them make sure they arent getting a raw deal when they do buy. so thx, this was not a popular question [clearly] but you helped, so +1 and verified-checkmark. cheers!